# Why did use "selenium" and the page did not go down?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, phantomjs

Why did you use "webdriver.PhantomJS" and the page did not scroll down?

I am crawling the Twitter website.

(The reason we do not use the api is to get past data.)

But the page does not scroll down, so I can not get more tweets.

What's wrong? How do I fix this code?

Also, I do not know how many pages end.

I do not think you should specify a number to get everything.
(Because I can not get all the data).

```
for _ in range(50):
    body.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
```

Is there any good way?

The code below is the complete code that I'm running.

```
#py3
import requests 
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS('C:\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/bin/phantomjs')
base_url = u'https://twitter.com/search?l=&q=money%20since%3A2017-07-18%20until%3A2017-07-20&src=typd&lang=ko'
url = base_url

browser.get(url)
time.sleep(1)

body = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body')

for _ in range(50):
    body.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
    time.sleep(0.2)

tweets=browser.find_elements_by_class_name('tweet-text')

wfile = open("money.txt", mode='w', encoding='utf8')
data={}
i = 1
for tweet in tweets:
    data['text'] = tweet.text
    print(i, ":", data)
    wfile.write(str(data) +'\n')
    i += 1
wfile.close()
```

Comment: "The reason we do not use api is to get past data" - not sure Twitter would be too happy about that. Good luck with that.

Comment: This question has been asked and answered a BUNCH of times on this site already. You really need to do some better searching before asking a question... same goes for the answer. These questions should be marked as duplicates.

Comment: I also wondered about this site. The questioner does not know how to apply it to his code. It seems that it is not until the duplication process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scroll to the end of the webpage with `browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")`. Is this what you're trying to accomplish?

To use this you need to scroll before grabbing the tweets. For example, replacing your first for loop with:

```
for _ in range(50):
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

Also, just a tip for your second loop. Instead of keeping track of i outside of the loop, you can use enumerate:

```
for i, tweet in enumerate(tweets):
    data['text'] = tweet.text
    print(i, ":", data)
    wfile.write(str(data) +'\n')
```

Comment: Yes, that's right! I want to finish the web page. But I do not understand this answer. Where does the response code run between the code (sentence) and the code?


I saw the answer and tried to solve it myself. But I can not get it wrong, not the whole. (I only brought 20tweets, but through this phrase I could get 40.
But there are still a lot of materials left.)

Comment: I added the code. The for loop will scroll through 50 pages of tweets, if there is some other end condition you want (e.g. scrolling through ALL of them) you'd need to code that in.

Comment: Thank you!. Your answer has been a great help to me. Thank you very much.

If you do not mind, can you get advice?
Gets all tweets in the URL.
(Scrolling through ALL of them)
About this code. 
Roughly predicted that range (n) to n
 In any case,
 I think there is a limit.

Comment: I'm sure there is a limit although letting this run for a bit didn't find one. There are a couple ways to get everything though. You could keep track of the height of the document and compare it each time you scroll checking that the height has increased. If it is ever the same you know you've reached the bottom. There might also be some element that twitter loads at the bottom of the search results, in which case you could check to see if that element has loaded.

Comment: It's only a guessing method. I thought this code was "all", "unlimited". Hahaha. Thank you very much for your reply.